# SNMP может читать данные из файла?

Tags: snmp

SNMP --help изучил, не нашел там , чтобы было возможно с какой нибудь командой прочитать содержание файла. Подтвердите, пожалуйста, я прав ?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1157